# Fixed part in custom painted usercontrol with autoscroll c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, custom-controls, autoscroll

I would like to create a table like control where a number of top rows stay in place when scrolling.
I paint the control in an override of the OnPaint method.

When scrolling some partial repaint happens automatically, but this creates artefacts and looks weird. To solve that I call Invalidate(); or Refresh(); in an eventhandler attached to the scroll event and take the scrollposition in to account when painting the part that is supposed to scroll in / out of view. However when I do this the part that is supposed to stay in place gets scrolled out and sent back again and again. (so it is sort of flickering)
I am trying to make this work smoothly without the flickering.

To simplify the issue I have made the following code where I draw a line that is supposed to stay in place when scrolling.
As you can see it starts flickering when scrolling.

I have already thought of doublebuffering and such as you can see in the code.

Does anyone know how to make the line stay in place?
Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ColumnReaderUITryOut
{
    public partial class CustomPaintScrollTest : UserControl
    {
        public CustomPaintScrollTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(500, 600);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            ResizeRedraw = true;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 0, Width, Height);
        }

        private void CustomPaintScrollTest_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried everything, only thing I see is to somehow prevent redraw that scroll causes (not your call to Invalidate) using Win32 API. Instead of doing this, maybe your control should have fixed header and  panel below it that is scrollable.